# Embedded Jetty+Jersey injection

Tags: jersey, jetty, embedded-jetty

The following code gives me null pointer exception when I try to get @Context Request req in a jersey resource.

```
 ServletHolder sh = new ServletHolder(ServletContainer.class);
 sh.setInitParameter(ServerProperties.PROVIDER_PACKAGES, "com.exchange.server.rest");

 Server server = new Server(9999);
 ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/",        ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
 server.setHandler(context);
 context.addServlet(sh, "/*");

 server.start();
 server.join();
```

If I don't mess with the request the resource is working fine.

any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing

@Context Request req (which is a org.eclipse.jetty.request) to 
@Context HttpServletRequest req works even though the first implements the iface.